# Petición axios no captura error y no muestra mensaje de success

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, axios, async-await

Estoy trabajando con react de lado del cliente y con express y mysql de lado del servidor. La petición al backend esta funcionando bien, el producto es creado correctamente y lo muestra en pantalla, pero no muestra el mensaje de success, al igual que el de error.

```
   import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import  { useState } from "react";
import Swal from 'sweetalert'


const ProductsAdd = () =>{
    
    const[product, setProduct] = useState({
        id: "",
        clave: "",
        nombre: "",
        descripcion: ""
    });

    const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        setProduct({...product, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
      
    }
    const onsubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(product);

        try{
            const post = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/products',{product})
            Swal('Producto agregado correctamente');

        }catch(e){   
            Swal('error');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Considera incluir el código o algún snippet que podamos replicar. Las imágenes de código hay que tratar de evitarlas :)

Comment: La consola te lanza algún error? Replique tu código y me funciona bien

Comment: No manda ningún error, lo único es que no muestra la animación o mensaje de success o error en la pagina web, una vez agregado el producto. Por parte del servidor si captura el error, cuando no se llena ningún dato del formulario o se repite un Id, y manda el mensaje por consola, pero en el frontend no lo muestra en la pagina ni tampoco en consola.

Comment: No está demás preguntar pero realizaste el `npm i` de sweetalert me imagino.. porque yo cree un sandbox y me funcionó de inmediato :(

Comment: exactamente que es un sandbox? jeje

Comment: Cumplen la misma función que un IDE como Visual Studio o editores con VSCode. Acá te dejo el [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-star-ecou8?file=/src/App.js) del que hice yo, basándome en tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

creo deberia considerar hacer una funcion que haga las peticiones de axios y asi evites repetir codigo por ejemplo asi y te deberia de servir. en el response.Message deberia estar el mensaje de error

```
 const PostInfo = async (path, body) => {
  return await axios.post(`${route}/${path}`, body).catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      return error.response.data;
    } else if (error.request) {
      return error.request;
    } else {
      return error.message;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta usar

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

try{
 const post = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/products',{product})
 Swal.fire(
  'Good job!',
  'You clicked the button!',
  'success'
)

}catch(e){   
 Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'Something went wrong!',
  footer: '<a href="">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
})
 }
```